# Pax device NFC support

Tags: android, kotlin, paxos, pax

As I am working on a pax project which is android based device. Devices are Pax A920 pro and Pax A920. Pax provide SDKs for these devices and for NFC reader of there is only support provided for Mifare ultralight and Mifare classic. But I need to make it work for Mifare desfire/ISO standard protocol and this is not supported by the PAX sdks. I tried to write android’s native NfcAdapter and NfcManager code to make my own functionality but it keep telling me to “NO NFC SUPPORT ON THIS DEVICE” but it works with pax sdks.

I have tried Triplinx sdks as well but still it doesn’t recognise the NFC and there is no support from PAX team as well for now.

Is there anyway to achieve this functionality or any libraries/sdks????

Tried android’s native classes and TRIPLINX sdk but it didn’t work.